# Detect duplicate elements python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I get continuously data from a server and can receive the data via the following line of code:

```
id, type, value = getId(payload)
```

After that I would like to write them into a file via:

```
out.write(str(id) + ";" + str(type) + ";" + str(value) + "\n")
```

Now the case is, that the same id can appear multiple times, but the value will be a different one. Therefore I would like to extend the out.write into the following way that the different values are added at the right side but still being referred to the same id:

```
out.write(str(id) + ";" + str(type) + ";" + str(value) + ";" + str(value1) + ";" + str(value2) + "\n")
```

Does anyone has an idea how to do this in python?

Comment: make a dict of dicts where id is key and value is another dict with type and value field and value should be array ?

Comment: I would use a [`defaultdict(set)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), mapping `id` to the unique set of `value`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the hints that were already added as comments you can create something similar to this:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

values = defaultdict(set)
types = dict()

for payload in input_stream:
    id, type, value = get(payload)
    values[id].add(value)
    types[id] = type

for id in types.keys():
    out.write(";".join(map(str, [id, types[id]] + list(values[id]))) + "\n")
```

If the values is more of a time series (order is important), then replace `set` with `list`.

Answer (score 2):

You want to keep a dictionary where the key in the dictionary is your `id` and the value is a `set` and you can add all the values

```
from collections import defaultdict
results = defaultdict(set)

id, type, value = getId(payload)
results[id].add(value)
```

This dictionary will then keep all the values per `id`.

It should be noted that using a set will remove the count of duplicates, so if you want to keep every value, including duplicates use a `list` instead